# Python: Nested for loops giving undesired output

Tags: python

```
_ax = ["Tim","Tom","Mat"]
_ay = [12,15,11]
_series = "["

for _x in _ax:
    _series = _series + '{"name": "%s"' % _x + ', "data": ['
    for _y in _ay:
        _series = _series + str(_y) + ","

_series = str(_series) + "]}]"
_series = str(_series).replace(",{","]},{").replace(",]","]")
```

Ideally the above code should give me the output as:

```
series: [{
        "name": "Tim",
        "data": [12]
    }, {
        "name": "Tom",
        data: [15]
    }, {
        "name": "Mat",
        "data": [11]
    }]
```

However the result I dervive is as follows:

```
  series: [{
        "name": "Tim",
        "data": [12,15,11]
    }, {
        "name": "Tom",
        data: [12,15,11]
    }, {
        "name": "Mat",
        "data": [12,15,11]
    }]
```

I am sure this has to do with the for loops.What is the best way to go about this?
PS: This is just a represenation of the actual code which is much larger and complex.

Comment: instead of making nested for loops, you should use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip). As it stands, it iterates through each `_y` at every iteration of `_x`

Comment: I see you like underscores, lol

Comment: In what format are you trying to serialize your data? You could use the `json` package or python's `pprint` and avoid having to do lots of manual steps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
_ax = ["Tim","Tom","Mat"]
_ay = [12,15,11]
_series = '[ ' + ', '.join([ '{ "name": "%s", "data": [%d] }' % z for z in zip(_ax, _ay) ]) + ' ]'
```

See [`zip()` documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) for more details.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you sir :) Well its so amazing both the loops can be avaoided with just 1 line of code. I will go through the documentation in detail.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is doing exactly what you asked to do:

```
for _x in _ax:
    _series = _series + '{"name": "%s"' % _x + ', "age": ['
    for _y in _ay:
        _series = _series + str(_y) + ","
```

The second for is simply dumping **ALL** elements in _y. It's equivalent to `",".join(map(str, _y)`, which creates an string with the elements in `_y` as a  coma separated list.

As noted in the comments, if you want to iterate on each element of `_x` and `_y`, you should use `zip` like:

```
for name, data in zip(_x, _y):
    _series += repr({"name": name, "data": [data]})
    _series += ','
```